# Pig - How to reference columns in a FOREACH after a JOIN when using positional notation?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

I have 2 tables orders and order_items

orders table contains (order_id, order_date,order_customer_id, order_status, order_month)
order_items contains (order_item_id, order_item_order_id, order_item_product_id, order_item_quantity, order_item_subtotal, order_item_product_price)

the tables are joined by orders.order_id and order_items.order_item_order_id
the datatype is not provided so positional notation is used.

```
orders = LOAD '/user/horton/orders' USING PigStorage(',');
order_items = LOAD '/user/horton/orders' USING PigStorage(',');
ordersjoin = JOIN orders BY $0, order_items BY $1 ; 
orderrevenuebydate = FOREACH ordersjoin GENERATE orders::$1,     order_items::$4;
```

I get the following error when trying to generate the FOREACH for orderrevenuebydate

> Unexpected character '$' 2016-06-19 19:17:22,757
>   [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:   Unexpected character '$' Details at logfile:
>   /home/6301dd50e3fac19f7c90fbf9898496/pig_1466356957630.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to directly reference the positional notation from the relation.

For example, if you want to generate *order_date* and *order_item_subtotal* fields from *ordersjoin* relation, use the below statement.

```
orderrevenuebydate = FOREACH ordersjoin GENERATE $1, $9;
```

Note that after the join operation, *ordersjoin* relation will contain all the attributes from two relations.